# Maven resolves wrong dependency version

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency

Our warfile contains not the expected SNAPSHOT-Version of a jarfile, it contains an older release version via another dependency.

**Simplified dependency:tree**

```
war-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT
\- jar1-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT
   +- jar2-x.x.x
   |  +- problemjar-x.x.x
   +- jar3-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT
```

jar3-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT has a dependency "problemjar-x.x.y-SNAPSHOT" (newer version), but the war project build (and the dependency:tree) contains "problemjar-x.x.x" from "jar2-x.x.x".

For now, we "exclude" "problemjar-x.x.x" for "jar2-x.x.x".

But it would be nice to know the reason for this behaviour, IMHO the exclusion is just a workaround.

**Notes:**

- The dependency "problemjar-x.x.y-SNAPSHOT" in "jar3-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT" is **not** "provided".
- The Maven version is 3.2.5
- The levels in the simplified dependency:tree above are correct, so the path to the older version is not shorter than the path to the newer SNAPSHOT version

**edit: project structure**

war and jar1 are children of one parent pom, the simplified dependency:tree is from the war project which has the jar1 project as a dependency. The others are normal/external dependencies, which applies to jar1 too as seen from the war project.

Comment: Are those dependencies of the WAR build within the same build( Multi module) or coming from other builds?

Comment: sorry, comment was wrong, no parent-child relation, war and jar1 are on the same level (children of multimodule). The rest are "normal" external dependencies.

Comment: It does not matter if they are coming from the same level or not..important is if they are within the same reactor (multi module build) if correctly referenced this can not happen only if you do things wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven does *not* take the newest version from the dependency tree.

It takes the nearest version, and in your case this is the first it encounters.

If you want to force Maven to take a specific version, it is better to use `<dependencyManagement>` instead of exclusions.

Comment: I don't think so, or can you point me to a corresponding original detail documentation? Imagine how many "exclusions" you'd have to write (or a "correct dependency order"), regarding one simple module with X external dependencies that use various versions of another external dependency.

Comment: Look up "dependency mediation" in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html, and also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201120/maven-set-dependency-mediation-strategy-to-newest-rather-than-nearest

Comment: In our company, we use dependencyManagement _a lot_, because Maven correctly determines groupId/artifactId, but trusting Maven regarding the version is problematic (at least in large projects).

Comment: Thanks for the mediation hint, question answered

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following:

1) Each child module should take it's version from it's parent, i.e. do not have a `<version>` tag only a `<parent>` tag that contains a version.

2) When you call the dependency from the same project always do it as follows:

```
<version>${project.version}</version>
```

Comment: sorry, comment was wrong, no parent-child relation, war and jar1 are on the same level (children of multimodule). The rest are "normal" external dependencies.